# Transparency around UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview

I have a UIView with a "advertisement" and I want to be able to have a UIWebView popup window appear over top of the advertisement.

I want to be able to have everything except the UIWebView become a dimmed black transparent.. Is this possible?

Let me know if this is clear or not. You see it on many websites

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIView *vie=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 480)];

[vie setOpaque:NO];

[vie setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


UIWebView *urwebiew=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 200)];


    //.................

[vie addSubview:urwebiew];


now the view is ready with transparent to use
```

Comment: Problem is that set's my uiwebview to transparent.. I want everything EXCEPT the webview transparent

Comment: then before present webview add plain view with transparent and then present uiwebview .after closing the webview remove that view from superview.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a view over the entire screen with a small alpha (making it more (close to 0) or less (close to 1) transparent). By setting userInteractionEnabled to NO, you can prevent anything under this view from responding to touch events. Then add your UIWebView to that.

Comment: Not a bad idea, ill give it a try